# Newtonsoft.Json serialization returns empty value from JwtPayload object in Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to serialize an object to the JSON string I received from the token payload. In .Net Core 2.2, it's working perfectly but when I upgrade to .Net Core 3.1 it doesn't work and return [] values.

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string jwtToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1OTU2NDk1MjIsImRhdGEiOnsiY2Fycmllcl90biI6IjgyMzg0NjI4MzQifX0.2PZ48UGYQi_LbW1kqnl-FqB330X1hSf5pVBjlbe6aY4";
        var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(jwtToken);
        var payLoad = token.Payload;
        var header = token.Header;
        
        var sbject = new object();
        var checkObject = payLoad.TryGetValue("data", out sbject);
        Console.WriteLine("Payload: " + payLoad.SerializeToJson().ToString());
        
        Console.WriteLine("Result: "+ JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sbject));

    }
}
```

Result

```
Payload: {"timestamp":1595649522,"data":{"carrier_tn":"8238462834"}}
Result: {"carrier_tn":[]}
```

I dont know why it return {"carrier_tn":[]} it should be {"carrier_tn": "8238462834"}
I have tried using the new System.Text.Json but got the exception The collection type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.Linq.JObject' is not supported.

Please help me regarding this problem. Thank you